# Show that $\lim_{z \to 0 }\frac{\log(z+1)}{z} = 1$ for the complex logarithm

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, logarithms

Show that $\lim_{z \to 1 }\frac{\log(z)}{z} = 1$ for the complex logarithm,
with the definition of the complex logarithm being
$$ \log(z) = \log |z| +  i \arg(z). $$

**Edit.** Ok, so it seems that it was typo in the textbook and it was corrected to

$$ \lim_{z  \to 1 } \frac{\log(1+z)}{z} = 1,$$
but which seems to be still wrong and it should be

$$ \lim_{z  \to 0 } \frac{\log(1+z)}{z} = 1\,?$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please share what have you tried after writing question.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Well, so far staring at it but that didn't help much. I tried substitute  the definition of the complex log, and thought if $z$ approaches 1 the $\arg(z)$ must go to zero but does $log \mid z \mid $, that would give me 0. So something is wrong.

Comment: Perhaps $\lim\limits_{z \to 1 }\frac{\log(z)}{z-1}$ or $\lim\limits_{z \to 0 }\frac{\log(1+z)}{z}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\lim_{z \to 1 }\frac{\log(z)}{z} = 1$ is not correct, since , for $z \to 1$ we get $\log z \to \log 1=0.$

Hence

$$\lim_{z \to 1 }\frac{\log(z)}{z} = 0. $$

I think that you mean $\lim_{z \to 1 }\frac{\log(z)}{z-1} $ . With $f(z)= \log z$ for $z \in \mathbb{C}\backslash\mathbb{R}_{\leq 0},$ we derive

$$\lim_{z \to 1 }\frac{\log(z)}{z-1}= \lim_{z \to 1 }\frac{f(z)-f(1)}{z-1}=f'(1)=1.$$

Answer (score 0):

Okay so since complex $\log$ is well defined at $1$ and is continuous in the domain $\mathbb{C}\backslash\mathbb{R}_{\leq 0}$. You can simply evaluate $$\lim \limits_{z \to 1}\frac{\log(z)}{z} = \frac{\log(1)}{1} = 0.$$

Maybe you just misread the question and the real question is the limit when $z\to -1$?

Comment: No, its from a textbook  and it states what I wrote. The text book is "Funktionen theorie Dietmar A. Salomon its in german, The question is on page 10.

Comment: So it's trivial, and the answer is $0$, not $1$

Comment: ok thanks! I think its a typo in the book.